# Java SDK - Setting Additional Attributes for a Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, fuel, sdk

I have been reading on here that the method to set attributes for triggered sends isn't available in the Java SDK.

Can anyone tell me if this is still the case? And if so, is the alternative to go back and use the API directly or is there way to add in this ability ourselves to the SDK or even access the API directly using the SDK.

Comment: You should be able to pass in attributes on the `ETSubscriber` object passed to the `Send` method - http://exacttarget.github.io/fuel-java/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not actually a java programmer (I use C#)  however our client uses java. I will pass this suggestion on to him. If you have a code sample that would really make our day! Thanks again, Jeanine

Comment: Neither am I. Just looking at the docs it appears that way.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old so you might already have the answer, but I'll still post this.

You can use the REST API to pass additional attributes to a Triggered Send. Http callouts are simpler than SOAP. You can modify the FUEL SDK library on Github and make it work but it's much more complicated than

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com 
POST /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:cust_key/send 
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
"From": {
    "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
    "Name": "Code@"
},
"To": {
    "Address": "example@example.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
    "ContactAttributes": {
        "SubscriberAttributes": {
            "Region": "West",
            "City": "Indianapolis",
            "State": "IN"
        }
    }
},
"OPTIONS": {
    "RequestType": "ASYNC"
}
}
```

Details can be found at the URL - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm